# Remove multiple array values inside a string

Tags: php

I want to remove or filter some images values which are not existing into another sting. In $description variable have 2 images values (images/bk5.jpg, images/bk3.jpg) and in $img variable have 4 images values and I want $imgs_result (images/bk5.jpg, images/bk3.jpg) and want to delete another 2 images values of the $img variable.

```
<?php 

$description ='Some paragraph... &lt;p&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;images/bk5.jpg&quot; alt=&quot;&quot; width=&quot;300&quot; height=&quot;242&quot; /&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;images/bk3.jpg&quot; alt=&quot;&quot; /&gt; Some paragraph...&lt;/p&gt;';

$img ='images/bk1.jpg images/bk3.jpg images/bk4.jpg images/bk5.jpg';

$imgpage = explode(" ",$img);

$imglength = count($imgpage);

for($x = 0; $x <= $imglength; $x++){
//This code delete the images from the database but does not remove or filter the values of variables.
   if(!stristr($description,$imgpage[$x])){

      $imgs_result = str_ireplace($imgpage[$x],"",$img);

      unlink($imgpage[$x]);

   }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a little of functional programming to do that:

```
<?php

$description ='Some paragraph... &lt;p&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;images/bk5.jpg&quot; alt=&quot;&quot; width=&quot;300&quot; height=&quot;242&quot; /&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;images/bk3.jpg&quot; alt=&quot;&quot; /&gt; Some paragraph...&lt;/p&gt;';

$img ='images/bk1.jpg images/bk3.jpg images/bk4.jpg images/bk5.jpg';

$imgpage = explode(" ",$img);

$imgs_result = array_filter($imgpage, function($image) use($description) {
    return stristr($description,$image);
});

print_r($imgs_result);
```

- To see the code working [here](https://3v4l.org/OHWbD).
- To learn more about functional programming [here](https://phptherightway.com/pages/Functional-Programming.html).
- Library that help you with functional programing in PHP [here](https://github.com/masterfermin02/slash).

Comment: You are welcome! Can you give me a vote up so someone else that need help with a similar situation can find it? @Sam

Answer (score -1):

If you have 2 strings, like these:

```
$description = "images/bk5.jpg, images/bk3.jpg";
$img = "images/bk5.jpg, images/bk3.jpg, images/bk1.jpg, images/bk2.jpg";
```

Firstly, you can use **explode()** function for convert your strings to arrays.
And then, you can use **array_diff()** function to find differencies between these arrays.

Comment: Ups, you've edited to the question. Now I'm looking at.